# IPTABLES restarting and possible consequences

Tags: iptables

I have iptables and masquerading enabled through this:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

How can I revert this rule? i.e I want to disable the masquerade.

I am afraid to test..because if I fail..there would be a lot of problems (for example lose ssh)

Also can I restart iptables hoping that it wouldn't start rejecting all conns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-D` to delete a rule from the selected chain:

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a rule, that functionality will be gone.

So any SSH sessions that depend on that rule will also disconnect.

Comment: wrong, it will affect new connections only in the case of MASQUERADE, and indeed any other rule you had in the nat table.

Comment: @Olipro While we appreciate your efforts, we can't let you dramatically change the meaning of someone's answer like that. You should post that as an Answer yourself. Thank you!